# Grabbing Variables from Application POST

Tags: php, android, symfony, doctrine

As part of a project I'm trying to make web portal for a open source Android application however I am having some trouble parsing some of the data coming from the application.

The following appears in the logcat when the application is sending the data:

```
Sending using 'POST' - URI: http://WEBSITE/api/v2/devices/133/data.json - parameters: {location[lat]=55.8275143, location[accuracy]=10.0, location[lng]=-1.6821027}
```

I'm just confused as to how I grab this data, at the moment I'm trying to use the following in Symfony with Doctrine:

```
$lat = $this->getRequest()->get("location:lat");
$lng = $this->getRequest()->get("location:lng");
$acc = $this->getRequest()->get("location:accuracy");
```

But this doesn't seem to grab the variables correctly. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: `$this->getRequest()->get("location");` returns you an associative array with keys as `lat` etc

Comment: The parameters bag uses a different format for deeper items.. try using `$lat = $this->getRequest()->get('location[lat]', null, true)`. For more info check our the second code block down at http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#accessing-request-data.

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function parseActionRequest(Request $request){
        $receivedRawData = $request->getContent() ;
        $parsedData = json_decode($receivedRawData, true);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using what was suggested by Qoop in the comments solved this issue:

> The parameters bag uses a different format for deeper items.. try
>   using $lat = $this->getRequest()->get('location[lat]', null, true).